# How to get distinct count value in scala

Tags: scala

I want to find the distinct values from this query in scala

```
select  
    key,     
    count(distinct suppKey)  
from  
    file
group by  
    key ;
```

I write this code in scala, but didn't working.

```
val count= file.map(line=> (line.split('|')(0),line.split('|')(1)).distinct().count())
```

I make split, because key is in the first row in file, and suppkey in the second.

File:

```
1|52|3956|337.0
1|77|4069|357.8
1|7|14|35.2
2|3|8895|378.4
2|3|4969|915.2
2|3|8539|438.3
2|78|3025|306.3
```

Expected output:

```
1|3
2|2
```

Comment: Can you post data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a file, for simpler testing, I use a String:

```
scala> val s="""1|52|3956|337.0
     | 1|77|4069|357.8
     | 1|7|14|35.2
     | 2|3|8895|378.4
     | 2|3|4969|915.2
     | 2|3|8539|438.3
     | 2|78|3025|306.3"""

scala> s.split("\n").map (line => {val sp = line.split ('|'); (sp(0), sp(1))}).distinct.groupBy (_._1).map (e => (e._1, e._2.size))
res198: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 3)
```

Imho, we need a groupBy to specify what to group over, and to count groupwise.

Comment: I have error

[error] C:\Users\SparkApplication.scala:37:27: value split is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

[error]                 val countOrder=filtered.split("\n").map (line => {val sp = line.split ('|'); (sp(0), sp(1))}).distinct.groupBy (_._1).map (e => (e._1, e._2.size))

[error] one error found

[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Comment: you need to use \\| to tell the compiler to treat it as a plain text

Comment: @EliasKonstantinou: Well, I wasn't aware of spark, being involved - you might add a spark tag to the question. Instead of `file`, I just used a String with line breaks for easy testing. With a String, the command as above works in the REPL without further masking. So I guess 'file' and/or `filtered` have either to be converted to String or a simpler path for mapping to lines has to be chosen - if `line` is of type String.

Answer (score 1):

Done in spark REPL. test.txt is the file with the text you've provided

```
val d = sc.textFile("test.txt")
d.map(x => (x.split("\\|")(0), x.split("\\|")(1))).distinct.countByKey

scala.collection.Map[String,Long] = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 3)
```

Comment: Υour way seems to work correctly but then I have to join this table with the following:

val amounts = whereCondition.map(line => (line.split('|')(0),line.split('|')(2).toInt * (line.split('|')(3).toFloat))).reduceByKey((a,b) => a + b)

    val result = theArrayCreatedWithYourWay.join(amounts)

    And I get this error:

    value union is not a member of scala.collection.Map[String,Long]

      Do you have any idea what is going on?